# Is there a way to recognize hand gestures in Meta Spark AR Studio?

Tags: gesture-recognition, spark-ar-studio

I want to place text based on the hand gesture. I see there is a way to track the whole hand, but can you do so for individual fingers (e.g. two fingers up, fist, open hand)?